# Wordpress Custom Post type and post type child filter

Tags: wordpress, filter, custom-post-type

i want to make a filter, where i can list employees

however the employees are from post type employees (example) and their contracts are made in child post type called contracts ( example ) so i have made this code but i can't take all info that i need

```
 $args = array( 'post_type' => array( 'employees', 'contracts'),
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'paged' => $paged,
     'orderby'=>'title',
     'order'=> $order,
     'meta_query' => array(
     'relation' => 'OR',
             array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-podruznici',
            'value' => $podruznici,
            'type' => 'CHAR',        
            'compare' => '='
            ),
          array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-direkcija_podruznica',
            'value' => $podruznici,
            'type' => 'CHAR',        
            'compare' => '='
            ),
          array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-opredeneno_neopredeleno_vraboten',
            'value' => $dogovor,        
            'type' => 'CHAR',        
            'compare' => '='
            )
     )
```

this array here

```
 array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-opredeneno_neopredeleno_vraboten',
            'value' => $dogovor,        
            'type' => 'CHAR',        
            'compare' => '='
            )
```

is from the post type contracts

so if in the filter i choose full time or part time i can only list the employees name and it does not give me the other data..

i hope it makes sense

Comment: Can you please add the php code, where you try to output the the results? If you get the titles of your employees on full or part time, the post query seems to be working.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sh62sp this is what it should look like but this is what i get when i tried to filter the child post https://prnt.sc/sh652j

Comment: Ok I think I understand the problem. But you are getting whole posts in your query, so the data should be there. I guess the problem happens in the output, so I need to code of it to take a look.

Comment: i don't have the site live, so i can share my file https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtBIIAc5khpTh95MwbUDrhGJFm_-KQ?e=bklsOV

Comment: Have you tried to take out the "'order_by'' or '"paged', maybe not the "meta_query" is the problem. Have you also tried to dumb the values where you save to form inputs? Does the order and filtering of the posts work in generally, but only that the title is displayed?

Comment: Yes i tried everything, but still the same, however i found different solution, have created new hidden fields where im putting the data in and then taking the sorting from there so i kind of fix it and its working for now :) but thanks for trying